# SAS Macro to create binary variables based on another variable's Null condition

Tags: null, sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset with over 300 variables where many numeric variables have a lot of nulls. I want to create an additional binary variable for each of them which will say if the variable is null or not.

Data Example

1. ID No_of_Visit No_of_Purchase *Flag_Null_No_Of_Visit Flag_Null_No_Of_Purchase*
2. 1  5    5  0   0
3. 2  12   1  0   0
4. 3  10   .  0   1
5. 4   .   .  1   1

Is there any quick way to create these null/no null flag variables for multiple columns?

Comment: So you want to go from 200 variables to 400 variables?  How do want to name these new variables.  Why do you think you need to have new variables?

Comment: I am trying to build a linear model with a Continuous Target. Variables with Null values have a business meaning which is different than Zero. So I want to handle the Nulls by adding one more variable to the model. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a new variable that identifies if it is null or not, it is better to use built-in array logic when working with this data. The array logic would functionally do the same thing to identify if a variable is null or not. The only difference is you're looking for a missing value rather than a 1, and you do not need to reference new variables. You're also keeping the size of your data smaller and reducing redundant variables.

```
data isnull;
    set have;
    array numvars[*] _NUMERIC_;
    array charvars[*] _CHARACTER_;

    do i = 1 to dim(numvars);
        if(missing(numvars[i]) ) then <logic>;
    end;

    do i = 1 to dim(charvars);
        if(missing(charvars[i]) ) then <logic>;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nmiss` over the array for numerical variables, and `cmiss` if they are character variables. The colon after `flag` below puts all variables beginning with the string "flag" into the array `flag_array`. In the output `some_null` will be 1 if any of the flags are missing, and 0 otherwise.

```
data mydata;
  set mydata;
  array flag_array flag: ;
  some_null = nmiss(of flag_array[*]); 
run;
```

Note in the latest version of SAS you don't need the `{*}` for the length of the array.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question, you want a flag for **each** column? Seems messy but I would do this.

```
data mydata (drop=i);
  set mydata;
  array flag_array flag: ;
  array null_flag [dim(flag_array)] ;
  do i = 1 to dim(flag_array);
    null_flag[i] = flag_array[i] = . ; /*shorter than if-else*/ 
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to generate code to create new variables. Here is SAS code that you could use.
If you really need a macro then figure out what the macro inputs are and then convert to a macro.

First get a list of the variables you want to convert.  Perhaps you just want the _NUMERIC_ variables?  You could use PROC CONTENTS or DICTIONARY.COLUMNS to do this. Or just use PROC TRANSPOSE:

```
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=names ;
   var _numeric_;
run;
```

Now use that list of names to generate the code to create the new variables.  You need to come up with new names for each variable.  If your original variables are short enough you could just add a prefix or a suffix.

```
filename code temp;
data names ;
  set names ;
  length null_name $32 ;
  null_name = cats('NULL_',_name_);
  file code ;
  put null_name '=missing(' _name_ ');' ;
run;
```

Now you can use that code in a data step to add the variables.

```
data want;
  set have;
%incldue code / source2;
run;
```